# Postgresql recursive count records dynamically

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, recursion

I am trying to count the records from a table of events records having close time intervals between event times and sharing the same criteria for other columns to detect the first occurrence event time and last cease time for each flapping event

I am using Postgres database and though it can be done using `with recursive` so I wrote the following code:

```
with recursive flapping as (
    select nodeid, problemtext,moid,eventtime,1 as count from sb.fm_power_alarms a where nodeid = 'DSA1738'

    union 
    select nodeid,problemtext,moid,f.eventtime,f.count+1
    from flapping f
    where nodeid=f.nodeid and moid=f.moid and problemtext=f.problemtext
    and eventtime-f.eventtime<'00:10:00'::interval and eventtime <>f.eventtime
)
select nodeid,problemtext,moid,eventtime, sum(count) from flapping
group by nodeid,problemtext,moid,eventtime order by eventtime desc
```

It didn't do the count right nor did it work the interval criteria

```
nodeid  problemtext moid    eventtime   sum
DSA1738 Major_Alarm DSA1738 10/24/2017 10:50    1
DSA1738 Major_Alarm DSA1738 10/24/2017 10:39    1
DSA1738 Major_Alarm DSA1738 10/24/2017 10:35    1
DSA1738 Major_Alarm DSA1738 10/24/2017 10:32    1
DSA1738 Major_Alarm DSA1738 10/24/2017 10:23    1
DSA1738 Major_Alarm DSA1738 10/24/2017 10:17    1
DSA1738 Major_Alarm DSA1738 10/24/2017 10:16    1
DSA1738 Major_Alarm DSA1738 10/24/2017 10:15    1
```

This is the DDL for the table:

```
CREATE TABLE sb.fm_power_alarms
(
  alarmid text NOT NULL,
  problemtext text,
  eventtime timestamp(0) without time zone,
  ceasetime timestamp(0) without time zone,
  nodeid text,
  moid text, -- TG / Cell id

  CONSTRAINT poweralarm_pk PRIMARY KEY (alarmid)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE sb.fm_power_alarms
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

And this is some insert statements to fill in test data

```
INSERT INTO fm_power_alarms (alarmid, problemtext,  eventtime, ceasetime, nodeid,  moid) VALUES ('1355236275', 'Major_Alarm',  '2017-10-23 18:21:59', '2017-10-23 18:27:38', 'DSA1738',  'DSA1738');
INSERT INTO fm_power_alarms (alarmid, problemtext,  eventtime, ceasetime, nodeid,  moid) VALUES ('1355236007', 'Major_Alarm',  '2017-10-23 18:19:25', '2017-10-23 18:21:28', 'DSA1738',  'DSA1738');
INSERT INTO fm_power_alarms (alarmid, problemtext,  eventtime, ceasetime, nodeid,  moid) VALUES ('1355237001', 'Major_Alarm',  '2017-10-23 18:28:08', '2017-10-23 18:31:13', 'DSA1738',  'DSA1738');
INSERT INTO fm_power_alarms (alarmid, problemtext,  eventtime, ceasetime, nodeid,  moid) VALUES ('1355237697', 'Major_Alarm',  '2017-10-23 18:31:44', '2017-10-23 18:32:45', 'DSA1738',  'DSA1738');
INSERT INTO fm_power_alarms (alarmid, problemtext,  eventtime, ceasetime, nodeid,  moid) VALUES ('1355068807', 'Major_Alarm',  '2017-10-23 07:17:30', '2017-10-23 07:18:32', 'DSA1738',  'DSA1738');
INSERT INTO fm_power_alarms (alarmid, problemtext,  eventtime, ceasetime, nodeid,  moid) VALUES ('1355068318', 'Major_Alarm',  '2017-10-23 07:10:20', '2017-10-23 07:10:50', 'DSA1738',  'DSA1738');
INSERT INTO fm_power_alarms (alarmid, problemtext,  eventtime, ceasetime, nodeid,  moid) VALUES ('1355068672', 'Major_Alarm',  '2017-10-23 07:15:58', '2017-10-23 07:17:00', 'DSA1738',  'DSA1738');
INSERT INTO fm_power_alarms (alarmid, problemtext,  eventtime, ceasetime, nodeid,  moid) VALUES ('1355068412', 'Major_Alarm',  '2017-10-23 07:11:21', '2017-10-23 07:15:28', 'DSA1738',  'DSA1738');
INSERT INTO fm_power_alarms (alarmid, problemtext,  eventtime, ceasetime, nodeid,  moid) VALUES ('1355237858', 'Major_Alarm',  '2017-10-23 18:33:47', '2017-10-23 18:52:45', 'DSA1738',  'DSA1738');
INSERT INTO fm_power_alarms (alarmid, problemtext,  eventtime, ceasetime, nodeid,  moid) VALUES ('1355063572', 'Major_Alarm',  '2017-10-23 05:54:58', '2017-10-23 05:55:28', 'DSA1738',  'DSA1738');
INSERT INTO fm_power_alarms (alarmid, problemtext,  eventtime, ceasetime, nodeid,  moid) VALUES ('1355063420', 'Major_Alarm',  '2017-10-23 05:51:54', '2017-10-23 05:53:56', 'DSA1738',  'DSA1738');
INSERT INTO fm_power_alarms (alarmid, problemtext,  eventtime, ceasetime, nodeid,  moid) VALUES ('1355063762', 'Major_Alarm',  '2017-10-23 05:58:02', '2017-10-23 05:59:34', 'DSA1738',  'DSA1738');
INSERT INTO fm_power_alarms (alarmid, problemtext,  eventtime, ceasetime, nodeid,  moid) VALUES ('1355427976', 'Major_Alarm',  '2017-10-24 10:50:00', NULL, 'DSA1738',  'DSA1738');
INSERT INTO fm_power_alarms (alarmid, problemtext,  eventtime, ceasetime, nodeid,  moid) VALUES ('1355045543', 'Major_Alarm',  '2017-10-23 04:55:29', '2017-10-23 04:57:32', 'DSA1738',  'DSA1738');
INSERT INTO fm_power_alarms (alarmid, problemtext,  eventtime, ceasetime, nodeid,  moid) VALUES ('1355044468', 'Major_Alarm',  '2017-10-23 04:50:52', '2017-10-23 04:51:54', 'DSA1738',  'DSA1738');
INSERT INTO fm_power_alarms (alarmid, problemtext,  eventtime, ceasetime, nodeid,  moid) VALUES ('1355045210', 'Major_Alarm',  '2017-10-23 04:53:56', '2017-10-23 04:54:27', 'DSA1738',  'DSA1738');
INSERT INTO fm_power_alarms (alarmid, problemtext,  eventtime, ceasetime, nodeid,  moid) VALUES ('1355379387', 'Major_Alarm',  '2017-10-24 09:41:18', '2017-10-24 09:48:30', 'DSA1738',  'DSA1738');
INSERT INTO fm_power_alarms (alarmid, problemtext,  eventtime, ceasetime, nodeid,  moid) VALUES ('1355019561', 'Major_Alarm',  '2017-10-23 03:58:35', '2017-10-23 03:59:35', 'DSA1738',  'DSA1738');
INSERT INTO fm_power_alarms (alarmid, problemtext,  eventtime, ceasetime, nodeid,  moid) VALUES ('1355019110', 'Major_Alarm',  '2017-10-23 03:54:59', '2017-10-23 03:55:29', 'DSA1738',  'DSA1738');
INSERT INTO fm_power_alarms (alarmid, problemtext,  eventtime, ceasetime, nodeid,  moid) VALUES ('1355351597', 'Major_Alarm',  '2017-10-24 08:51:04', '2017-10-24 08:57:43', 'DSA1738',  'DSA1738');
INSERT INTO fm_power_alarms (alarmid, problemtext,  eventtime, ceasetime, nodeid,  moid) VALUES ('1355018573', 'Major_Alarm',  '2017-10-23 03:53:26', '2017-10-23 03:54:29', 'DSA1738',  'DSA1738');
INSERT INTO fm_power_alarms (alarmid, problemtext,  eventtime, ceasetime, nodeid,  moid) VALUES ('1355019461', 'Major_Alarm',  '2017-10-23 03:57:02', '2017-10-23 03:57:32', 'DSA1738',  'DSA1738');
INSERT INTO fm_power_alarms (alarmid, problemtext,  eventtime, ceasetime, nodeid,  moid) VALUES ('1355019140', 'Major_Alarm',  '2017-10-23 03:56:01', '2017-10-23 03:56:31', 'DSA1738',  'DSA1738');
INSERT INTO fm_power_alarms (alarmid, problemtext,  eventtime, ceasetime, nodeid,  moid) VALUES ('1354985670', 'Major_Alarm',  '2017-10-22 23:57:35', '2017-10-22 23:58:37', 'DSA1738',  'DSA1738');
INSERT INTO fm_power_alarms (alarmid, problemtext,  eventtime, ceasetime, nodeid,  moid) VALUES ('1354985044', 'Major_Alarm',  '2017-10-22 23:49:23', '2017-10-22 23:50:24', 'DSA1738',  'DSA1738');
INSERT INTO fm_power_alarms (alarmid, problemtext,  eventtime, ceasetime, nodeid,  moid) VALUES ('1354985502', 'Major_Alarm',  '2017-10-22 23:55:01', '2017-10-22 23:57:05', 'DSA1738',  'DSA1738');
```

I need the output to look like this minding the difference between records' event times

`nodeid, moid, first_eventtime, last_ceasetime, number_of_records`

I have spent so much time trying to make it work and find a way to include the cease time criteria . I can use all the help I can get.

Comment: It will be easier for us to help if you also provide example data and desired result.

Comment: @ŁukaszKamiński  sure. I added the DDL and insert stamtements

Comment: `where nodeid=f.nodeid and moid=f.moid and problemtext=f.problemtext` These  all refer to the same table reference (since **there is only one table** in the FROM clause)

Comment: @joop . I see. so what should be changed ?